# Using VS 2008 Team Systems for One Man Shop

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have VS 2008 Team Systems Suite and I am a one-man shop.  I am about to start a new project and want to use versioning of code.  Can this be done on a single computer with using the VS 2008 Team Systems Suite?  I have used Perforce in the past but want to use the versioning in VS 2008 if that is possible.  I would not be running this on a separate server but isolated completely on a laptop.  Any helpful links are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a virtual machine with a server where you install the TFS server. Then run that virtual machine on your laptop. That way, the day you'reno longer a one-man shop you can easily move the virtual machine to another server instead of using your laptop.